# Postgres local restore of Heroku backup changes datetime fields ahead by 4 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm restoring a downloaded Heroku Postgres backup on my mac to do some testing. All of the datetime columns (in every model) have been moved ahead by 4 hours. Need to fix it.

Seems like it must be a timezone issue, but my local server instance is on the same timezone as the Heroku instance. ( same Time.zone.to_s results in my local console and the Heroku console )

Any ideas?

EDIT: I checked the Heroku postgres instance, and it's timezone is UTC (checked via SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE')). The difference between the timezones of the postgres instances feels like the issue.

I'm trying to set my local postgres instance to UTC, but it keeps flipping back to EDT.

FIXED: In application.rb changed config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc from config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

Comment: Is your timezone "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"?

Comment: timezone is a  `config.time_zone` setting in your `application.rb` or in your `production.rb` file. please look into that - make sure that it's set accordingly

Comment: Yes, app is in "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", specified in application.rb. The postgres db is also in Canada/Eastern (checked via SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE') )